# How can I get PDO bindValue/bindParam to bind with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been using mysql and mysqli in the past, but am starting a new project, so wanted to go back to OOP with PDO-mysql .. however, it doesn't want to work:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
    {

        $pwdHasher = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);
        $hash = $pwdHasher->HashPassword($_POST["password"]);
        //$insert = $dbh->prepare('insert into users (username,password) values ("?","?")');
        $insert = $pdo->prepare("insert into users (username,password) values (?,?)");      
        $insert->bindParam(1,$_POST["name"]);
        $insert->bindParam(2,$hash);
        $insert->execute();
        echo "Registration Success!";
    }
```

edit: The above code works if I change the code from the commented line to the non-commented (i.e. single quote to double quotes) However, this doesn't work later:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("select * from users where username = ?");
$query->bindParam(1,$_POST["name"]);
$result = $query->execute()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should clarify, on one project I can choose mysqli or PDO, on the other project I can only use PDO or mysql. Since mysql is deprecated, I'm leaning towards using PDO so I only have to remember one way to do things. edit: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you've found the answer to your first question.
For the second one it would be

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

called right after connect.
it will tell you what's going wrong with your query.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

also always helps with such errors like misspelled variables ($pdo is not $dbh for example)

Comment: sneaky! Agree on always setting ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, if you send it directly on the class instantiation you will also get exceptions if database connections fails.

Comment: Your Common Sense - I changed $pdo - $dbh also as an experiment, and have error_reporting(E_ALL) as well. -- the answer to the question is double quote vs single quote when making the prepare statement.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use ? for placeholders, you are supposed to send an array to the execute-method matching the positions of the question marks. `$insert->execute(array('value1', 'value2'));`

You could however use named placeholders `.. WHERE x = :myxvalue` and use `$insert->bindValue(':myxvalue', 'thevalue', PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Also, please have a look at the difference between `bindParam` and `bindValue`

Comment: Looking through the documentation I realize that it is actually possible to bind using question mark index with bindValue. Could it be you missing out on specifying the parameter type?

Comment: I get the bindParam and bindValue difference, but that doesn't explain why it isn't replacing anything. edit: I changed from binding to named placeholders to binding to indexes as an experiment when the former didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this question is simple and embarrassing:
 I need to change the single quotes surrounding the sql statement being prepared to double quotes (and remove the double quotes where the '?' mark is.
change:

```
$insert = $dbh->prepare('insert into users (username,password) values ("?","?")');
```

to

```
$insert = $dbh->prepare("insert into users (username,password) values (?,?)");
```

and everything works.

Comment: It would work just as well with single quotes, as long as you dont quote the question marks. using bindValue and telling PDO what kind of parameter this is ensures proper handling.

Comment: Hank, you're right, it's the double quotes inside that were causing trouble. Thank you for your help with this! -- also I'll be sure to specify the type so there are no chances for additional errors due to typecasts